# How to fix connection from HTML form to Spring MVC?

Tags: java, html, spring-mvc, jsp

I am having problems with connecting the HTML form to the Spring MVC RequestMapping.

I have tried form:form using the modelAttribute with no success. This always give me "Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name..." error. I searched similar questions, but the answers given still gave me errors, or the HTTP 404 Not Found page.

This is User_accountControl.java

```
public class User_accountControl {
    @Autowired
    private User_accountDAO user_accountDAO;

    @RequestMapping(value="/newUser", method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView newUser(ModelAndView model) {
        User_account newUser = new User_account();
        model.addObject("user_account", newUser);
        model.setViewName("/account");
        return model;
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="/saveUser", method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public ModelAndView saveUser(@ModelAttribute("user_account") User_account user_account) {
        user_accountDAO.addUserAccount(user_account);
        return new ModelAndView("redirect:/account");

    }
}
```

This is Home.jsp

```
<html>
<head><title> Account </title> </head>
<body>
<h1> Welcome </h1>

<form method="post" action="saveUser">
<label for="username">Username</label><input type="text"  id="username"/><br>
<label for="password">Password</label><input type="text" id="password"/><br>
<label for="name">Name</label><input type="text" id="name"/><br>
<label for="email">Email</label><input type="text" id="email"/><br>
<button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

I expect the output of the HTML page to display the fields and allow the user to insert the information and submit it. Once submitted it should redirect the user back to the account.jsp page.

Comment: Did you add `@RestController` above `public class User_accountControl {`?

Comment: @acarlstein Yes I added the `@RestController` and still getting the same problem. :(